# Tokenize JSON data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, tokenize

I am having one JSON as :

```
{\"A\":\"1.354534634,\",\"B\":\"-0.432335,\",\"C\":\"0.234123423,\"}
```

I need to tokenize this with Javascript and I need to assign values like that:

```
Accel_X = value of A, ie. 1.354534634

Accel_Y = value of B, ie. -0.432335

Accel_Z = value of C, ie. 0.234123423
```

I can use `slice()` . But that is a bad way to do that for a larger instance and not good way to code. So, How can I do that ?

Comment: why cant you `JSON.parse` it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to escape those quote marks in the JSON for a start:

```
var json = '{"A":"1.354534634,","B":"-0.432335,","C":"0.234123423,"}';
```

Parse it:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Then just assign to your variables, removing the commas.

```
var Accel_X = obj.A.replace(',', '');
var Accel_Y = obj.B.replace(',', '');
var Accel_Z = obj.C.replace(',', '');
```

Note: this will assign the numbers as *strings*. If you want them as floating point numbers you need to do a type conversion too:

```
var Accel_X = parseFloat(obj.A.replace(',', ''));
var Accel_Y = parseFloat(obj.B.replace(',', ''));
var Accel_Z = parseFloat(obj.C.replace(',', ''));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yjcb3L72/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON.parse for it.

```
var a = "{\"A\":\"1.354534634,\",\"B\":\"-0.432335,\",\"C\":\"0.234123423,\"}";

var b = JSON.parse(a);

Accel_X = b.A;
Accel_Y = b.B;
Accel_Z = b.C;

console.log(Accel_X,Accel_Y,Accel_Z);
```